# Using a `with` context manager in SQLAlchemy Core how do I know if a transaction rolled back?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The [SQLAlchemy CORE doc for transactions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#using-transactions) suggests using a `with` context manager as follows:

```
# runs a transaction
with engine.begin() as connection:
    r1 = connection.execute(table1.select())
    connection.execute(table1.insert(), col1=7, col2='this is some data')
```

or

```
with connection.begin() as trans:
    r1 = connection.execute(table1.select())
    connection.execute(table1.insert(), col1=7, col2='this is some data')
```

Either way, how do I know if a transaction was executed and committed, or if it was rolled back?

Answer (score 8):

If it doesn't raise, it committed. If you look at the docs, you'll note that the with-statement is more or less equivalent to:

```
connection = engine.connect()
trans = connection.begin()
try:
    r1 = connection.execute(table1.select())
    connection.execute(table1.insert(), col1=7, col2='this is some data')
    trans.commit()
except:
    trans.rollback()
    raise
```

Regarding the comment: a with-statement is not, necessarily, a replacement for try/except in case you need exception handling – such as when you want to know if the transaction rolled back or not.

If you have to perform additional cleanup or for example logging when a transaction rolls back, you'll still have to wrap the with-statement in a try/except, but you can be sure that the transaction has been dealt with before control passes from the block governed by the with-statement:

```
try:
    with ...:
        ...

except ...:
    # rolled back

else:
    # committed
```

You could also opt to reraise the error so that other parts can also handle their cleanup. Of course for example logging could be handled by another context manager as well:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def logger(log, error_msg="Oh woe!"):
    try:
        yield

    except:
        log.exception(error_msg)
        raise

...

with logger(log), connection.begin():
    r1 = connection.execute(table1.select())
    connection.execute(table1.insert(), col1=7, col2='this is some data')
```

In this case as you've noted in the comment a try/except has been eliminated, or hidden, by using a with-statement, in the spirit of [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#introduction):

> This PEP adds a new statement "with" to the Python language to make it possible to factor out standard uses of try/finally statements.

Comment: How does one know if an exception was raised?

Isn't the point of using the context manager so as to eliminate `try/except`

Comment: By wrapping the code that may raise in a `try: ... except ...: ...`. The point of a with-statement is to handle certain tasks/resources like closing open files, or committing/rolling back transactions, in a way that doesn't depend on you remembering to actually do all that (in every possible branch etc.).

Comment: [The aforementioned docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#using-transactions) (as the suggested edit queue is full)

Answer (score 2):

Since the rollback is performed in case of an exception, if the code after the `with` executes, you can rest assured that the transaction has not been rolled back.

If you additionally need to *test* for that case, you can use the usual python constructs such as:

```
try:
    with connection.begin() as trans:
        r1 = connection.execute(table1.select())
        connection.execute(table1.insert(), col1=7, col2='this is some data')
except:
    # The transaction has been rolled back, you can log or otherwise
    # react to that fact
    ...
    # Finally, propagate the exception to the caller. If you choose not
    # to propagate, then don't use `except:`, but handle a narrower
    # class of exceptions.
    raise
```